# Will individual website owners have to do anything to implement DNSSEC?

Tags: domain-name-system

According to this [article](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2019-02-22-en), "ICANN is calling for full deployment of the Domain Name System Security Extensions (DNSSEC) across all unsecured domain names." As someone who runs my own e-commerce servers, will I need to make any changes to how I set up my domain names and configure DNS for my servers or is this something that will only require actions by people at a higher level (e.g. my webhosting provider)?

Answer (score 0):

DNSSEC is an optional setting. If you aren't using a third party for DNS resolution (such as CloudFlare) it should be as simple as a checkbox at your registrar.